# Access image URI from adapter

Tags: java, android

I have a main activity, in which the user is shown a dialogue to pick an image from the gallery or use the camera. The problem is ( I think ) that i'm building against the 6.0 APIs and the permissions are what's messing me up.

When the application passes the Uri (As a string) into a database, the Adapter has to access that database and get the picture and put it into an ImageView.

I get the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to access the file in the MainActivity, but I think I also need it in the adapter, but I can't access permissions from in there.

//TL;DR how can I access the internal storage (pictures) from inside of a recyclerview adapter class?

Here's my code:

After I check for permissions, I start the intent to pick the image:

```
//RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 0;
Intent toGal = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(toGal, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

then, inside of the onActivityResult, I get the URI and set a variable to it's string value

```
boolean request = requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_CAMER || requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && request && imageReturnedIntent != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();            
        picturePath = String.valueOf(selectedImage);
        Log.i(TAG, picturePath);
    }
```

And then I store it in a Realm database, and access it from the adapter. I know this is not the problem, because I can log the path that was stored in the db that points to the image just fine.

Here is where I access it inside of the Adapter:

```
String imgString = Model.getImage(); //This is "/emulated/storage/pathtoimg.jpg"
if (imgString != null) {
        Bitmap BM = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgString);
        ImageView.setImageBitmap(BM);
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. When I try to request permissions from inside the Adapter it says it needs to be an activity so how can I access the internal storage from a recyclerview adapter?

Comment: "When the application passes the Uri (As a string) into a database" -- that's not going to work reliably. Use the `Uri` you get back from `onActivityResult()` immediately. If you need access to the data in the future, you will need to make a copy of that data (e.g., copy the image) into your app. The `Uri` may no longer be any good in the future, particularly if it is a `content://` `Uri`.

Comment: @Plays2  : you need to ask permission inside activity then onRequestPermission Result you can trigger same work again ! other wise you need to have the context of activity which is bad design